# Type hint for types.MappingProxyType

Tags: python, type-hinting

How would the type hint look like for a `types.MappingProxyType` object?

For instance for

```py
schema = types.MappingProxyType(
    {
        "name": "foo",
        "email": [
            {
                "private": "foo@bar.com",
                "active": True
            }
        ]
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

`MappingProxyType[str, str | list[dict[str, Unknown]]]`

If you're using Pylance in VSCode, the types can be inferred